# Android: Drawing custom shapes

Tags: android, android-shapedrawable

I want to draw a custom shape like this-[image: Custom Shape].

One option is to make each shape in photoshop individually and then use it in coding but I want to know that is it possible to draw this using xml?

How should I draw the shape like this? Don't expect complete code, just give me idea or point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try the following shape drawable xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<!-- Colored rectangle-->
<item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <size 
            android:width="100dp"
            android:height="40dp" />
        <solid android:color="#FAD55C" />
    </shape>
</item>

<!-- This rectangle for the left side -->
<!-- Its color should be the same as layout's -->
<item
    android:right="90dp"
    android:left="-30dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>

<!-- These rectangles for the right side -->
<!-- Their color should be the same as layout's -->
<item
    android:top="-40dp"
    android:bottom="63dp"
    android:right="-25dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>

<item
    android:top="63dp"
    android:bottom="-40dp"
    android:right="-25dp">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="-45">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
</layer-list>
```

That's how it looks like on a white background:

[image]

Here is more info on [Shape Drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape).

**EDIT:**

The following is a small explanation of how it's done.

1. We place a yellow rectangle of 100 x 40 dp size. From now on this rectangle can be treated as a container for the rest of the shapes. The boarders of the container are considered as origins for the boarders of shapes we're going to place within the container. Namely, setting *`top, bottom, right and left`* attributes of the *`size`* tag of shape means the distance from the shape's borders to *`top, bottom, right and left`* edges of the container (yellow rectangle).

For example, if we want to place a smaller rectangle inside of the yellow one with a `10dp` gap from each yellow rectangle's edge we'd set the `top, bottom, right and left` attributes equal to `10dp` for the new (inner) rectangle.

2. In order to achieve an arrow-like shape for the right side of the yellow rectangle we use two white rectangles appropriately moved to the right and rotated. Notice, the *`size`* tag attribute's values can be negative which means that the corresponding edge of the shape appears outside of the container. In the previous example, if you set, say, the *`left`* attribute to 100 dp or higher, the inner rectangle won't show up, because it'll be behind the right boarder of the yellow one.

Regarding rotation, it goes clockwise for positive values and counterclockwise otherwise.

3. For the left side shape it's enough to use just one rectangle moved to the left (partially outside of the container) and 45 degree rotated.

Hopefully, this didn't confuse you.