# Triangle shape using xml in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-shape

I a created triangle shape following this [post](http://looksok.wordpress.com/2013/08/24/android-triangle-arrow-defined-as-an-xml-shape/)

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <item>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="45"
        android:toDegrees="45"
        android:pivotX="-40%"
        android:pivotY="87%" >
        <shape
            android:shape="rectangle" >
            <stroke android:color="@color/transparent" android:width="10dp"/>
            <solid
                android:color="@color/your_color_here" />
        </shape>
    </rotate>
</item>
```

But I have not been able to incline it towards the right or the left.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please give reason why to close this question ?

Comment: This question has two flags: "too broad" and "off-topic". Essentially, your question is of the type "is such a thing possible, and if so how?" You would do much better to make an attempt yourself, try some things out, and show progress. If there's a point where you're stuck in your particular implementation, then go ahead and ask about that specific issue.

Comment: @AdamHawkes thanks for the valuable remarks. Ok...so I tried to create this design...created triangle, rectangle, separately in pieces...I am trying to create this design.

Comment: @AdamHawkes actually multiple things are in my mind....not sure whether I should use xml for this design or I should design it using android.graphics.drawable.shapes.Shape

Comment: I'm not well versed in either of these techniques, so I cannot say what the capabilities are or which would be a better tool for your situation. My contribution here to help you understand why the question was flagged to be closed.

Comment: @AdamHawkes Ok...anyways thanks Adam.

Comment: @AdamHawkes Please review the question so that it can be opened again

Comment: It's not totally up to me, but I nominated it to be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could create this layout by overlaying different shapes one after another like it is shown in the selected for best answer in this question [Android: Drawing custom shapes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311785/android-drawing-custom-shapes) First `<item>` could be your rectangle and then you could use one rectangle and one triangle for the pointer