# How to create a Concave view on edit text android

Tags: android, android-edittext, concave

I am trying to achieve the view present in the below picture

> I tried all possible solution that I found but didn't worked for me

My tried code

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/fab_margin">
    <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:src="@drawable/des"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        app:border="true"
        app:border_color="#864543"
        app:border_width="8dp"
        app:shadow="false"
        android:id="@+id/view" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:background="#435467"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/view"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/fab_margin"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have tried below link ticked ans and also try to manipulate it according to my view but didn't succeed

[How to create EditText with rounded corners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646415/how-to-create-edittext-with-rounded-corners)

[image]

> Is I am on right way? This cant be achieved by making a XML in drwable and use it as background??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311785/android-drawing-custom-shapes   

Can this link can help

Answer (score 0):

Make TextView lower than ImageView.

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="105dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <com.pkmmte.view.CircularImageView
        android:layout_width="105dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:src="@drawable/des"
        android:elevation="1dp"
        app:border="true"
        app:border_color="#864543"
        app:border_width="8dp"
        app:shadow="false"
        android:id="@+id/view" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="111"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:paddingLeft="55dp"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is I am on right way? 
This cant be achieved my making a XML in drwable and use it as background??

I dont have much experience of development

Comment: I think you can't create a XML drawable like this.But you can use a pricture as background of the textView.

Comment: using a picture will not be feasible because of different screen sizes Right?

Comment: No.A picture is enough.Try to change a picture to 9patch.http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/

Comment: If size of circleview at left is fixed.The height  fo background is fixed.Use 9patch to fit screen width.http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311785/android-drawing-custom-shapes   

Can this link can help

Comment: It's useless.It can only be fixed height and width.What's the height of your TextView?