# Android drawable shape in xml

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, vector-graphics

How I can create single **vector xml drawable** like this (black shape):

[image]

**To be able** to use this in imageView and **change it color**

Comment: The explanation proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26320942/3290339) might help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create the required shape as a vector drawable, use the following code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="48dp"
    android:height="48dp"
    android:viewportHeight="12"
    android:viewportWidth="12">

<path
    android:fillColor="Set_Your_Color"
    android:pathData="M 2,9 C 2,9 4,10 6,10 C 8,10 10,9 10,9 L 10,0 2,0 2,8"
    android:strokeWidth="0.1"/>

 </vector>
```

Edit the values in the vector to fit it exactly to your requirements.

To use the vector drawable in ImageView, you can either do it programmatically using:

`image.setImageResource(R.drawable.myDrawable);`

or by XML:

`app:srcCompat="@drawable/mydrawable`