# How to clip semi circle at top center of ImageView(Android)

Tags: android, android-canvas, clip, oval

I need to clip a semi circle at top center of the ImageView like in the cd cover below
[image: CD Cover]

As I didn't worked on canvas in Android,I have no idea to achieve this!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following approach:

1) Create a Relative layout with 2 elements: 
 - A semi Circle shape 
 - You image

2) Align the semi circle on the image view 
3) Make Your linear layout as a custom view (optional) else directly use it

Comment: i want that semi circle to be transparent.It should clip way the image like in the cd cover

Comment: Then you can make a custom shape and set this image as its background

Comment: can you guide me to make one?As i never worked on custom shapes before,i have no idea to achieve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26311785/android-drawing-custom-shapes/26320942

This answer pretty much has all you need to know to make one